# Is it possible to get CPFP information from full node, without requesting full mempool dump?

Tags: json-rpc, mempool, replace-by-fee, child-pays-for-parent

I want to get CPFP information out of a full node—that is, `ancestorsize` and `ancestorfees`—in order to calculate the necessary fee for either CPFP, or RBF if possible.

Can I get this information through an RPC without requesting the full mempool dump?

I need this to build tools for CPFP/RBF, that are connecting to full node via RPC. But I can only find the full mempool dump, which is inefficient for this. (I don't need the full dump for one transaction information).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is `getmempoolentry`.

https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/help/getmempoolentry